# Received buffer containing actual data with some garbage values

Tags: c, buffer

I have this peice of code(function) where I am receiving an input buffer packet as first param and its length as second param. The buffer that I am receiving contains some data which need but alongwith some garbage values. I just need to print the actual data (ignoring the garbage values). How do I do that?

Here goes the (simplified version) code:

```
void decodeResp(char* in_buf, int *Len)
{
    char msg_buffer[100]    =   {0};

    memcpy(msg_buffer,(in_buf),*Len);

    printf("\n********** Response Recieved: [%s] **********\n",msg_buffer);
}
```

Suppose if `in_buf` contains `ACTUAL_DATA+(some garbage)`, I need to print just "ACTUAL_DATA" ignoring the garbage values. How do i put a check for that? The above peice of code will print everything.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put '\0' at msg_buffer[Len] position. Or maybe use Len instead of *Len, if it is not a pointer. Make sure that you copy right number of bytes, because in your code there are zeroes in buffer at the beginning and %s should work fine.

Comment: What is the garbage data? If you know what to expect, you can make a filter for it. Also, is the garbage data always appended to the actual data or is it between the data? If it's appended, @IvanIvanov's solution would work fine.

Comment: And also make sure that all symbols are 1 byte or use other data type (not char). Copy string with strcpy.

Comment: @IvanIvanov The problem is that the ìn_buf` which I receive, itself comes like `ACTUAL_DATA+(some garbege)` (and it's always appended). And the `Len` (its a pointer) is also the total length of the data received (actual + garbage). If i put `\0` at msg_buffer[*Len], it will get appended after the garbage. And it still won't work.

Comment: @ivy_lynx. No, I do not know what to expect. It can be of any length (within limits). And the garbage is always appended. I just need a way to differentiate between the actual data and the garbage so that i can just keep a marker in between and just print upto that marker.

Comment: @NeeldhwajPathak If you can tell that there's garbage, how do you make it out? There has to be some way to describe in code, what you do in your head when you differentiate the two.

Comment: Why do you think it is garbage? Maybe, problem in transmitter, not in receiver. If it tells you wrong Len and put garbage there.

Comment: @ivy_lynx. You have a genuine doubt there. I don't blame it. How do i know that there is some garbage? I am using MSVS and did put a breakpoint at the entry to this function and while debugging it, checked out the actual contents of the in_buf. :)

Comment: @NeeldhwajPathak I'm not doubting you, it wasn't a philosophical question. My point was, if you can tell that there's garbage, you can define what is garbage and isn't through code.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, how do you plan to differentiate between **ACTUAL DATA** and **garbage**?

If the **ACTUAL DATA** size is known prior to calling this function, send that value in `*len`, perform `memcpy()` for that particular size [don't forget to add the trailing `\0` to use as string].

If you need to perform the check inside `decodeResp()`, filter the `in_buf`, calculate the length of the **ACTUAL DATA**, do `memcpy()` for that size and print.

---

**EDIT**

It seems you are receiving the packet through some `socket`. You can make use of the return value of [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) call to supply `*len` to `decodeResp()`, just in case you are using some uninitialized buffer to receive the incoming packet.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out:

```
    char msg_buffer[100]    =   {0};
```

only sets the 1st element of msg_buffer to 0.

Your function should look like this:

```
void decodeResp(char* in_buf, int *Len)
{
    char msg_buffer[100] ;
    memcpy(msg_buffer, in_buf, *Len);

    in_buf[*len] = 0 ;

    printf("\n********** Response Recieved: [%s] **********\n",msg_buffer);
}
```

Assuming that `*Len` contains 4 and `in_buf` points to "ABCDXXX", "XXX" being garbage and "ABCD" being the actual data.

In `decodeResp` upon entry, `msg_buffer` contains random leftover values, for example "ghijklmnop".

After the call to memcpy, `msg_buffer` contains "ABCDklmnop".

If you printf now `msg_buffer` without `in_buf[*len]=0`, you will get "ABCDklmnop" as output. With `in_buf[*len]=0 ;` you will get "ABCD" as output.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Just one thing. You misunderstood the question a little. if `in_buf` points to "ABCDXXX", then *Len that i am receiving is 7 and not 4 (The *Len contains the total length including the garbage length). The problem here is that with every call to the function `decodeResp()` the actual data length will vary. The actual data will be alphanumeric always and garbage is some garbage taken from memory.

Because after `memcpy(msg_buffer, in_buf, *Len)` msg_buffer will contain "ABCDXXX" and doing `in_buf[*Len] = 0` will be in_buf[7] = 0. And this won't help me in solving my problem :)

Comment: Well if the length is wrong then there is no way to tell if the end of the buffer is garbage or not. For example: length = 7, buffer content = "ABCD&%ç". In that case "&%ç" is definitely garbage (not alphanumeric) and the actual data is "ABCD". But what happens if length is 7 and the buffer contains "ABCDKLM", there is absolutely no way to tell if "KLM" is garbage or actual data.

Comment: Ohkay!. Thanks for your time Michael. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @NeeldhwajPathak: you could embed the actual length of the data at the start of the buffer on the **sender** side, for exemple in the first 4 bytes. Then on the receiver side you know the actual length of the data.

Comment: It's not true that "`char msg_buffer[100]    =   {0};` _only sets the 1st element of msg_buffer to 0._" C Standard, section **Initialization**: _If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, ... the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration._